# cannot run BRIEF_demo on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv

I am trying to run BRIEF_demo-0.5 on my linux environment..
As instructed in the read me file i change my directory to the file BRIEF_demo-0.5 and typed make but i got the following errors..

```
g++ `pkg-config opencv --libs` main.o BRIEF.o -o BRIEF_demo
main.o: In function `matchDescriptors(CvMat&, CvMat&, std::vector<std::bitset<256ul>, std::allocator<std::bitset<256ul> > >, std::vector<std::bitset<256ul>, std::allocator<std::bitset<256ul> > >, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&) [clone .constprop.66]':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f6): undefined reference to `cvInitMatHeader'
main.cpp:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `cvInitMatHeader'
main.o: In function `drawQuadrangle(_IplImage*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, CvScalar, int) [clone .constprop.71]':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x333): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x398): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3f2): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.o: In function `waitKeyAndHandleKeyboardInput(int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x485): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
main.o: In function `drawQuadrangle(_IplImage*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, CvScalar, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5c6): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x625): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x68d): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x6e4): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.o: In function `drawAPlus(_IplImage*, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x867): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x8ce): more undefined references to `cvLine' follow
main.o: In function `takeNewFrame()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x99c): undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'
main.cpp:(.text+0x9be): undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
main.o: In function `showMatches(int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xb37): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.o: In function `rotateImage(_IplImage*, _IplImage*, CvPoint2D32f const&, float)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf0a): undefined reference to `cv2DRotationMatrix'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf68): undefined reference to `cvWarpAffine'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf90): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
main.o: In function `fpsCalculation()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11ac): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.cpp:(.text+0x11d0): undefined reference to `cvGetTickFrequency'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1211): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.o: In function `showOutput(_IplImage*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x12f5): undefined reference to `cvPutText'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1308): undefined reference to `cvGetTickFrequency'
main.cpp:(.text+0x13ab): undefined reference to `cvPutText'
main.cpp:(.text+0x13be): undefined reference to `cvGetTickFrequency'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1467): undefined reference to `cvPutText'
main.cpp:(.text+0x147a): undefined reference to `cvGetTickFrequency'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1529): undefined reference to `cvPutText'
main.cpp:(.text+0x153c): undefined reference to `cvGetTickFrequency'
main.cpp:(.text+0x15eb): undefined reference to `cvPutText'
main.cpp:(.text+0x15fe): undefined reference to `cvGetTickFrequency'
main.cpp:(.text+0x16ad): undefined reference to `cvPutText'
main.cpp:(.text+0x174a): undefined reference to `cvPutText'
main.o: In function `extractKeypoints(std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, int, _IplImage*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x17b3): undefined reference to `cvSetImageROI'
main.cpp:(.text+0x17c0): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(_IplImage const*, bool)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x17d3): undefined reference to `cv::FAST(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, int, bool)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x183b): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1843): undefined reference to `cvResetImageROI'
main.cpp:(.text+0x18c4): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x18ec): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1938): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
main.o: In function `chooseFASTThreshold(_IplImage const*, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x197d): undefined reference to `cvGetSize'
main.cpp:(.text+0x198e): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x19ab): undefined reference to `cvCopy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x19f6): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
main.o: In function `saveNewTemplate()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b50): undefined reference to `cvCopy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b5a): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b6c): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b7d): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b8f): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1bab): undefined reference to `cvSetImageROI'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1bc0): undefined reference to `cvCopy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1bcc): undefined reference to `cvResetImageROI'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1be1): undefined reference to `cvSetImageROI'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1bf6): undefined reference to `cvCopy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c02): undefined reference to `cvResetImageROI'
main.o: In function `learnTemplate()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x20da): undefined reference to `cvGetSize'
main.cpp:(.text+0x20ed): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2106): undefined reference to `cvCopy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2162): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x21c0): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x21d9): undefined reference to `cvResize'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2259): undefined reference to `cv2DRotationMatrix'
main.cpp:(.text+0x22b7): undefined reference to `cvWarpAffine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2323): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2351): undefined reference to `cvGetSize'
main.cpp:(.text+0x235e): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x239e): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
main.cpp:(.text+0x23ca): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
main.o: In function `takeNewTemplateImage()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x24a5): undefined reference to `cvCopy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x253f): undefined reference to `cvRectangle'
main.o: In function `matchDescriptors(CvMat&, CvMat&, std::vector<std::bitset<256ul>, std::allocator<std::bitset<256ul> > >, std::vector<std::bitset<256ul>, std::allocator<std::bitset<256ul> > >, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2736): undefined reference to `cvInitMatHeader'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2758): undefined reference to `cvInitMatHeader'
main.o: In function `init()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x27b4): undefined reference to `cvCreateCameraCapture'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27d0): undefined reference to `cvSetCaptureProperty'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27e9): undefined reference to `cvSetCaptureProperty'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2802): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2822): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2842): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x286c): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2889): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x28a6): more undefined references to `cvCreateImage' follow
main.o: In function `init()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x294b): undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
main.cpp:(.text+0x295c): undefined reference to `cvSetMouseCallback'
main.o: In function `doDetection()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2a4f): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2a8f): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ab7): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ae4): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2b04): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e28): more undefined references to `cvGetTickCount' follow
main.o: In function `doDetection()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3116): undefined reference to `cvFindHomography'
main.cpp:(.text+0x32b2): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
main.cpp:(.text+0x333f): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.cpp:(.text+0x336a): undefined reference to `cvPerspectiveTransform'
main.cpp:(.text+0x336f): undefined reference to `cvGetTickCount'
main.o: In function `run()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x34f4): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
main.cpp:(.text+0x35a0): undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'
main.cpp:(.text+0x35c2): undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
main.cpp:(.text+0x35dc): undefined reference to `cvCopy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3671): undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3693): undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
main.cpp:(.text+0x36a8): undefined reference to `cvCopy'
main.o: In function `showOutput(_IplImage*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x175f): undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
main.o: In function `init()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x298f): undefined reference to `cvInitFont'
BRIEF.o: In function `CVLAB::BRIEF::~BRIEF()':
BRIEF.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
BRIEF.o: In function `CVLAB::BRIEF::~BRIEF()':
BRIEF.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
BRIEF.o: In function `CVLAB::BRIEF::BRIEF()':
BRIEF.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
BRIEF.o: In function `CVLAB::BRIEF::allocateIntegralImage(_IplImage const*)':
BRIEF.cpp:(.text+0x868): undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
BRIEF.cpp:(.text+0x877): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
BRIEF.o: In function `CVLAB::BRIEF::getBriefDescriptors(std::vector<std::bitset<256ul>, std::allocator<std::bitset<256ul> > >&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, _IplImage*)':
BRIEF.cpp:(.text+0x9cd): undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
BRIEF.cpp:(.text+0x9dd): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
BRIEF.cpp:(.text+0x9f0): undefined reference to `cvIntegral'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [BRIEF_demo] Error 1
```

so... as instructed i one of the posts i tried the command 
g++ main.cpp BRIEF.cpp -lm -lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore
and i got

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lml
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcvaux
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcxcore
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when i type pkg-config  opencv --libs  --cflags i am getting
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann

please help...

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
g++ `pkg-config opencv --libs` main.o BRIEF.o -o BRIEF_demo
```

should read:

```
g++ main.o BRIEF.o -o BRIEF_demo `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

or, if you're editing the makefile:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

i.e. move the `$(LDFLAGS)` to the end of the line.

What's happening is that the linking to dependent libraries is skipped because at the time they are specified they are not actually needed. They are needed once the main.o and BRIEF.o files have been processed, so they will be linked in at that point.

It's a quirk of linking.